# Writing java bmi and bmr calculator use metric conversion

Tags: java

I seem to have gotten my self lost in my own programing. directly below is what the outcome is suppose to look like. I am desperately needing help as am new to java coding and becoming quickly aware I am not very good at. Please fill free to correct the code as needed. I learn better when i know what the mistake is. Thank you for any help you can provide.

This program implements a Health Assistance Calculator

Given a weight, height, and age, it will compute:

BMI - body mass index

Calories needed per day to maintain weight

Please enter your weight in pounds: 150

Please enter your height in inches: 66

Please enter your age in years: 30

Your BMI is 24.3

A BMI in the range of 18.5 to 24.9 is considered normal

To maintain your current weight:

Men need 2249 calories per day

Women need 2018 calories per day

Method 1: A method to display an explanation of what the program will do to the user.
o This method will not have any parameters or return values.
Method 2: A method to compute a person’s BMI. This method must:
o Have 2 parameters: weight in kgs and height in meters
o Use the pow method from in the java.Math class to square the height
o Return a double value: the calculated BMI
Methods 3 & 4: Two methods to compute the caloric requirements, one for a man and one for a
woman. Each of these methods must:
o Have 3 parameters: weight in kgs, height in meters, and age
o Convert the height to centimeters.
o Compute the caloric requirements.
o Use one of the rounding methods in the java.Math class to round the answer to a whole
number before returning it. Note that you may need to use casting to convert the value
returned from the java.Math method to an integer.
o Return an integer value: the daily calories required to maintain current weight
Method 5: A method to display the results, with no return value. This method must:
o Have 3 parameters: a person’s BMI, men’s calories, and women’s calories
o Display a description and the BMI, rounded to one decimal place using the printf method
from the System.out class
o Display the daily calories required to maintain current weight for men
o Display the daily calories required to maintain current weight for women

```
enter code here


package healthy;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Healthy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
printIntroduction(); 
double kg = .453592;
double feet = .3048;        
double bmi = BMIinput(console);
double age = InputAge(console);
double Wt = InputWeight(console);
double Ht = InputHeight(console);
double MetricConvert = Metric();
String status = getStatus(bmi);
String converted = getConverted(MetricConvert);

}
//Prints program description
public static void printIntroduction(){
System.out.println("This program Implements a Health Assistance Calculator")
System.out.println("Given a Weight, Height, and age, it will compute: ");
System.out.println("    BMI - body mass index");
System.out.println("    Calories needed per day to maintain weight");
System.out.println("");

} 
//Prompts user to input weight, height and age.
public static double BMIinput(Scanner console){
    System.out.println("Please enter your weight in pounds: ");
    double Inputweight = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("please enter your height in inches: ");
    double Inputheight = console.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("please enter your age in years: ");
    double InputAge = console.nextDouble();
            return BMIto(weight, height);
}  
// Calculates BMI based on user inputs
public static double BMIto(double weight, double height){
    return weight / Math.pow(height, 2);
}
// convert input height and weight to metric
public static String getConverted(double Metricconvert){
    double Ht * kg;
    double Wt * feet;
    return getConverted;
}
// displays Users Health status based off of bmi
public static String getStatus(double bmi) {
    if (bmi < 18.5) {
    return "A BMI below the range 18.5 to 24.9 is considered  underweight}
    } else if (bmi < 25) {
        return "A BMI in the range of 18.5 to 24.9 is considered normal";
    } else if (bmi < 30) {
        return "A BMI above range of 18.5 to 24.9 is considered overweight";
    } else {
        return "A BMI over 30 is obese";
    }   
}
} 
public static double round(double value, int digits) {
return Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, digits)) / Math.pow(10, digits);
}

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with this piece of code, including the fact that it does not even compile. You've got a good number of syntax issues that are causing this.

For example, your local variable declarations inside method `getConverted(double Metricconvert)` are broken. I'm not sure exactly what the calculation you wanted should look like, however a more correct method definition would look like this (This is of course based off of the fact you have fields `Ht` and `Wt`, and that they should be class variables.

```
public static void getConverted(double Metricconvert) {
    Ht = Metricconvert * kg;
    Wt = Metricconvert * feet;
}
```

Another example of a syntactic error is an issue with one of your `String` return values (This one: `A BMI below the range 18.5 to 24.9 is considered  underweight`). You've ended that return statement with a closing bracket, and it should be closed with a quotation mark `"`.

You should first fix the syntactical errors in this piece of code, and then work on the other issues, such as incorrect output.